# How to set a faultCode in a SOAPFault?

Tags: java, soap, soapfault

Why can I set a faulString, but can't I set a custom fault code in a SOAPFault? When I throw the exception, the text "Code X" does not appear in the SoapFaultException. Someone could tell me why? Thanks.

```
SOAPFault soapFault = SOAPFactory.newInstance(SOAPConstants.SOAP_1_1_PROTOCOL).createFault();
soapFault.setFaultString("String Y")
soapFault.setFaultCode("Code X");

throw new SOAPFaultException(soapFault);
```

Answer (score 6):

It is possible to get the fault code in the soap response with the following example:

```
String faultString = "String Y";
String faultCodeValue = "Code X";
QName faultCode = new QName("nameSpaceURI", faultCodeValue);
SOAPFault soapFault = null;
try {
    soapFault = SOAPFactory.newInstance(SOAPConstants.SOAP_1_1_PROTOCOL).createFault(faultString, faultCode);
    throw new javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException(soapFault);
} catch (SOAPException e1) {
    //
}
```

I get the following soap fault back:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <S:Body>
        <S:Fault xmlns:ns4="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns="">
        <faultcode xmlns:ns0="nameSpaceURI">ns0:Code X</faultcode>
        <faultstring>String Y</faultstring>
        </S:Fault>
    </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 4):

From [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/xml/soap/SOAPFault.html#setFaultCode%28java.lang.String%29):

> Fault codes, which given information about the fault, are defined in
>   the SOAP 1.1 specification. This element is mandatory in SOAP 1.1.
>   Because the fault code is required to be a QName it is preferable to
>   use the setFaultCode(Name) form of this method.
>
> `faultCode` - a `String` giving the fault code to be set. It must be of
>   the form `"prefix:localName"` where the prefix has been defined in a
>   namespace declaration.

Notice that the fault code your're setting has to be this format: `prefix:localName`. You're setting: `Code X`, that is why you do not see it. Use [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/xml/soap/SOAPFault.html#setFaultCode%28javax.xml.namespace.QName%29) method and all should be OK.